# If a (possibly convex?) set can be partitioned into several convex sets, must the boundary of these convex sets be linear?

Tags: general-topology, geometry

Let me try to formalize my question. For a given (possibly convex) set, does there exist a finite partition of it such that 1. every cell of the partition is a convex set; and 2. every boundary point of every cell of the partition is an extreme point?

The motivation of this question is that when we put balls into a box, the gap between balls must be non-convex. If we instead put cubes into a box, then the box can be partitioned into several convex sets. And I just realized that the set can be partitioned into infinite singletons where "linear boundary" seems to be not well-defined. So maybe we should only consider finite partitions.

I really appreciate your help, thank you very much!

Comment: Your question is not very clear: what does it mean for a set to be "linear"?  It might help you to follow MSE conventions and include the full statement of the question in the body of your question rather than relying on the title to give important information: that might help you see that you haven't given all the relevant information.

Comment: I feel like I am missing something, but what about disections of a circle?

Comment: @Rob Arthan Thanks for the question. I don't have a clear idea of "linearity" in my mind, but I will try to give a definition anyway.

Comment: @JasonDeVito What do you mean by "disections of a circle"? Splitting it through radius?

Comment: Let $B$ be the closed unit ball around the origin in $\mathbb{R}^2$.  Let $U= \{(x,y)\in B: x>0\}$ and let $V=\{(x,y)\in B: x\leq 0\}$.  Don't $U$ and $V$ form a partition of $B$ into convex sets where the boundary is not linear?

Comment: @JasonDeVito $x=0$ is linear.

Comment: Yes, part of the boundary is linear, but not the rest.  (Is there a notion of "boundary" for convex sets which differs from the topological notion of boundary?)

Comment: @JasonDeVito I see your point. Maybe I should rephrase this as something like boundaries that are adjacent to other cells.  But I don't know a specific notion of boundary for convex sets.

Comment: Perhaps you are only interested in where the boundaries of the two pieces intersect?  So, perhaps an equivalent form of your question is "Given two disjoint convex sets $A,B$, must $\partial A\cap \partial B$ be a union of line segments?"

Answer (score 1):

Consider two adjacent subsets $A$ and $B$ that share some portion of their boundaries. Pick two points $p,q$ on this shared boundary. Since $A$ is convex, the entire segment $pq$ lies in $A$. By the same argument the segment $pq$ also lies in $B$. If the shared boundary had curvature, this would not be possible.

---

Here is a picture in dimension 2 of what can go wrong if two adjacent subsets share a curved boundary. Here, there are two points of $B$ near the boundary such that the connecting line segment does not lie in $B$. The intuition in dimension 3 is similar.

[image]

Comment: Your argument $pq$ lies in $A$ relies on $p \in A$ and $q \in A$. Then $pq$ lies in $B$ relies on $p \in B$ and $q \in B$, which is impossible because $A$ and $B$ should be disjoint by the definition of partition.

Comment: @Ypbor You can modify my argument by considering points near the boundary if you don't want to deal with the issue of the boundary only belonging to one of the subsets.

Comment: @Ypbor Added a picture for intuition

Comment: That is exactly the intuition. Maybe the only concern is that "curvature" sounds like an informal term (I know the term refers to "the degree of curvature", but I think that is not what you mean here).

Comment: @Ypbor I think the condition is that the boundary itself needs to be a convex subset in $\mathbb{R}^3$.